# What tool is this -used for scoring the tiles by hand?

Tags: tiling

It can be seen in this video. Is it worth buying ?
https://youtu.be/0gGYOIkOVkk?t=164

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a scoring tool. If you've ever had to cut glass, it is similar to the wheel on a glass cutting tool.

If you are using a tile saw (wet saw), then this is not necessary. If you have a lot of tile to cut, you'll be a lot happier with a proper power saw. You can rent them from a lot of rental centers.

Using a scoring tool and snapping the tiles like in the linked video is OK in a pinch, but it has a high risk of breaking the tile or leaving it chipped. In general, it doesn't give the nicest edge, so it's best to avoid that technique if the edge will be visible.

Comment: agree... I already own a ridgid wet saw and it is a fantastic tool, I have trouble to spot the cut edge ..I have to mark it because it is still visible if you look two times and compare it with the opposite edge . The wet saw is very useful when I do work that must be very precise. However I have a project coming to do the floor for these connected spaces: laundry, hallway, kitchen, hallway. That will involve a lot of cuts with the edges mostly under drywall or trim so I do care how chipped is the edge but being able to cut quickly a large volume of tiles will help, hence the interest

Comment: @MiniMe you might want to consider using an angle grinder with a diamond cutting wheel. If the edges will be hidden, you can use the grinder and freehand those cuts pretty quickly.

Comment: I have that one two but score and snap if the fastest way to cut ...angle grinder is good for special cuts

Comment: I generally agree, but a power saw is much slower. Whether it's appropriate depends on the type of tile. Pros much prefer scoring cutters if they do the job, such as with glazed wall tile.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this tool:
Manual Tile Cutter, Multi-Functional Glass Cutter Set, Diamond cutting head, Ceramic Tile Opener,Professional Easy Glide Glass & Tile Cutter for Thick Glass Mosaic and Tiles Cutting

[https://www.amazon.com/Multi-Functional-Diamond-cutting-Ceramic-Professional/dp/B085HPXF26](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085HPXF26)